# Compiling Component in React Native for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, react-native

I am trying to port a functionality I have started and its working for React Native in iOS to Android. 
The component is a Audio Sound waveform visualiser, which is working fine in iOS, but I'm finding an issue when I try to build the Android Studio project.
In the Gradle console it shows up:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:ReactAndroid:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:checkReleaseManifest
:ReactAndroid:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:prepareReleaseDependencies
:ReactAndroid:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:createNativeDepsDirectories UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:downloadBoost FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:downloadBoost'.
> Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.945 secs
```

For some reason it crashes in the Gradle task when executing
 `:ReactAndroid:downloadBoost`

I've checked the https link manually and I can download the zip perfectly, so it may be the issue somewhere else.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with `react-native run-android` ???

Comment: Yes I tried, I've just going though the hard way, trying to compile the React Facebook libraries form the source NDK... Now it's working for me just doing and innocent 'add module' to the Android Studio...